# Select from multiple tables with OR condtions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and I'm having a difficult time trying to get the results from a SELECT query that I want. I've to select records from 3 tables given below:

Client(clientID,name,age, dateOfBirth)

Address(clientID, city, street )

Phone(ClientID, personalPhone, officePhone, homePhone)

In my input I could have (dateOfBirth, steet, homePhone) and i need Disntinct ClientIDs in result. These input values are optional. its not mandatory that every time all these input values will have value, in some scenarios only street and homePhone is provied, or sometime only street is provided.

There is "OR" relationship in the arguments! like if i pass homePhone even then record(s) should be returned.

Comment: What's your current SELECT statement look like?

Comment: `I'm using SQL Server` - so why the MySQL and Oracle tags?

Comment: SELECT clientID FROM CLIENT.CLIENT  where dateOfBirth = :dateOfBirth
intersect
SELECT clientID FROM CLIENT.Address where steet= :street 
intersect
SELECT clientID FROM client.Phone where homePhone= :homePhone

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Seems strange that our example code has a colon pre-fix for variables -- are you really using sql-server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost the same as Mureinik's answer, but he didn't use left outer joins, so if you had a client with an address but without a phone number, they would be excluded from the result-set UNLESS you use an outer join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT client_id
FROM   client c
LEFT OUTER JOIN   address a 
    ON c.client_id = a.client_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN   phone p 
    ON c.client_id = p.client_id
WHERE  (@date_of_birth IS NULL OR c.date_of_birth = @date_of_birth) AND
       (@street IS NULL OR @street = a.street) AND
       (@home_phone IS NULL OR @home_phone = p.home_phone)
```

Comment: it didn't work, i tested it with inputting only home_phone and no record returned when actually there is a record exists in phone table with this home_phone :(

Comment: Are you passing null values if the user doesn't include those values - or are you just passing empty strings?  You want to make sure they're null - or you would have to change conditional logic to (@date_of_birth = '' OR c.date_of_birth = @date_of_birth).  But send null values.  Much better than checking for empty strings.

Comment: Leaving for weekend.  I'll flag this question and answer on Monday if still unresolved.

Comment: @user3077985 I revisited this to help, but you haven't answered the question.  I'm assuming you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could short circuit the logic using `or` conditions. Let's assume you denote the arguments with a `@`:

```
SELECT    DISTINCT client_id
FROM      client c
LEFT JOIN address a ON c.client_id = a.client_id
LEFT JOIN phone p ON c.client_id = p.client_id
WHERE     (@date_of_birth IS NULL OR c.date_of_birth = @date_of_birth) AND
          (@street IS NULL OR @street = a.street) AND
          (@home_phone IS NULL OR @home_phone = p.home_phone)
```

Comment: You should use left outer joins, since your query will exclude records for which either the address or phone number is missing.  Given the limited information in the post, we don't know if phone number and addresses are required for a client record to be inserted.

Comment: there can be some records in Client table with a clientID which does not have records in address or phone number table(s).

Answer (score 0):

The standard way you have null default to "all" or wildcard is like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM client c
LEFT JOIN address a ON c.client_id = a.client_id
LEFT JOIN phone p ON c.client_id = p.client_id
WHERE (COALESCE(@date_of_birth,c.date_of_birth) = c.date_of_birth 
    OR COALESCE(@street,c. a.street) =  a.street
    OR COALESCE(@home_phone,p.home_phone) = p.home_phone )
 -- Put the following line in if you want at least one parameter to not be null
 AND COALESCE(@date_of_birth,@street,@home_phone) is not null
```